# Installing gdal with conda and setting environmental variables

Tags: python, conda, gdal

I have been trying to get the **gdal** library work using Python 2.7 and Anaconda in Windows 8 environment.

Besides gdal, I have also installed libgdal (frankly, I don't really understand the difference between the two). I now seem to have gdal 2.1.0 and 2.0.2 as well as libgdal 2.1.0.

However, when I run my Py code, there is a gdal error:

> 'gdalwarp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have already set the GDAL_DATA environmental variable to point to

> C:\Anaconda\pkgs\libgdal-2.1.0-vc9_0\Library\share\gdal

I have also added a path, although I am not entirely sure where this should point to:

> C:\Anaconda\pkgs\libgdal-2.1.0-vc9_0\Library\bin

I have tried the same with gdal 2.0.2 without success. gdalwarp.exe does seem to exist under libgdal 2.1.0 and gdal 2.0.2.

Any ideas? Is there an issue with the installation or have I not set the environmental variables correctly?

FYI, I have tried various installation commands, notably:

```
conda install gdal
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
conda install -c anaconda gdal
```

**Addendum**: I have found a manual solution: I set the GDAL_DATA and PATH variables in the terminal (pointing to libgdal 2.1.0) before running the code...

However, there is still an issue when I run my Py code: it is supposed to convert a tiff file to shp with gdal_polygonize:

```
cmd = 'gdal_polygonize.py %s -f "ESRI Shapefile" %s'%(dst_tif, dst_shp)
```

There is no error but the shapefile is not created (which leads to an error later on in the code). Any ideas as to why gdal is still not working correctly?

I have tried pointing the env variables to osgeo:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\scripts
set GDAL_DATA=C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal
```

Gdalinfo works but the gdal_polygonize used in my Py code does not appear to work.

Answer (score 4):

The key is the activation script which is (potentially) executed when activating the environment. Not every GDAL build for Conda contains this. In my experience recent Conda-Forge builds are really good.

With your requirements of py27 and GDAL 2.1 i can get it working by following these steps:

1) Create a new environment: `conda create -n gdaltest python=2.7`

2) Activate: `activate gdaltest`

3) Install GDAL: `conda install gdal=2.1 -c conda-forge`

4) Reactivate environment: `deactivate` + `activate gdaltest`
This forces the just installed activation script to be executed, this sets the environment variables.

If i start python and run `os.system("gdalinfo")`, i can see its picked up correctly. And running `os.environ['GDAL_DATA']` confirms the path is set correctly.

You can view the (de)activation script yourself at:
`C:\Miniconda3\envs\<env name>\etc\conda\activate.d\gdal-activate.bat`

A few years ago this didn't work as well as it does today, so make sure you have a recent Conda version (4.3.x) etc.

The benefit of this method is, that when switching environments, your paths are also changed accordingly. A "hard coded" `GDAL_DATA` path could potentially cause some compatibility issues if you mix and match different GDAL versions (although normally is should work OK).